# Access data from template to Vue Instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I'm very new to vue, so this is properly a basic question. I have a value in my template from an parsed object prop like this:

```
<h1>{{myval.theme}}</h1>
```

This gives and display the value in the browser. However, I need to obtain the value and store it in the data section of the instance. How can I store the data in the "getTheValue" data string? This is what I currenct have, and this does not work:

```
props: {
    myval: Object
  },
data() {
    return {
      getTheValue: this.myval.theme
     };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way its to use `computed` here

```js
computed: {
  getTheValue() {
    return this.myval.theme
  }
}
```

and call it same way:

```js
this.getTheValue
```

its best solutions - cached, non-reactive

---

also if you still want to use `data` you can assign in lifetime-hooks like:

```js
mounted() {
  this.getTheValue = this.myval.theme
}
```

But its crude solution, and I highly recommend to use computed variant

Comment: It gives me undefined cuz the data comes from a props which fetches it...

Comment: `return this.myval.theme ? this.myval.theme  : 'Loading..'` - try this

Comment: Then it return "Loading..." ?

Comment: Until your props will loading yes, then automatically replaced by your value

Comment: Also, you can render component when you have the value <comp v-if="myvalue" :myval="myvalue"